# Testing my ADX calculator

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I'm trying to program an [Average Directional Index](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adx.asp) (ADX) calculator in python, however I don't know if it is correct since I'm still a bit shaky on the financial side of things. I haven't found an ADX calculator online (surprisingly) so I can't compare it.

Should the following datasets generate the following ADX-values?

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] --> 100

[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] --> 100

[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512] --> 100

[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5] --> 0

[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3] --> 94.50548937857359

Could anyone with sufficient knowledge tell me if something seems off?

Comment: Might help if you gave us a pointer to where ADX is defined.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking and how this relates to personal finance. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I'm guessing that http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adx.asp defines the ADX he means (either that or http://www.adx.ae/English/Pages/default.aspx)

Comment: What's the point of writing when ta-lib python exists

Answer (score 2):

The calculation is explained in detail here:-

[StockCharts.com - Average Directional Index (ADX)](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:average_directional_index_adx)

The page includes a downloadable demo spreadsheet:-

[image]

Comment: this article is quite vague about the formulas

Comment: @Harkal Fully working spreadsheet example though, with simple formulas.

Comment: i checked it brother. the values are rounded off wrong and moreover the -+DM14 is not explained correctly. i figured it out using some other website